# Python: shp file to GML using OGR

Tags: python, shapefile, gml

I am trying to convert a shapefile to GML 3.1.1 . I am using gdal 1.9.1 however the GML conversion it generates for a geometry feature is GML 2 and it also swaps the long/latitude coordinates. Are there simple workarounds to keep the coordinate positions the same, while changing the output to GML 3.1.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the [axis order confusion](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/491/), where some software expects (x,y) = (long,lat) (the Shapefile way), and others as lat,long (I suppose, the traditional spoken way?).

Read more about the axis order options in the [GML GDAL Driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gml.html), which can be passed to OGR in either command-line or Python fashion. Try `GML_INVERT_AXIS_ORDER_IF_LAT_LONG=NO` (or is it `YES`?).